# Node.js App Deployment Issue - Error: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found

Tags: node.js, hosting, cpanel, bcrypt

I am encountering a deployment issue with my Node.js application on a cPanel hosting environment. When I attempt to access my application at `https://api.openlogistique.com/`, I receive the following error message:

[image: Error Screenshot]

After investigating further, I examined the error.log, which pointed to a problem with locating the file `/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` and specifically mentioned the missing version `CXXABI_1.3.8`. Here is the relevant error log snippet:

```
App 3693421 output: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1282
App 3693421 output:   return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
App 3693421 output:                  ^
App 3693421 output: Error: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/xysexpvg/nodevenv/api/16/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node)
App 3693421 output:     at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1282:18)
...
```

I have verified that the `/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` file is indeed installed on my hosting server, so I'm puzzled by this issue.

Could anyone kindly provide some guidance or a solution to resolve this problem? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.